# Way to delegate command to methods in different files

Tags: javascript, performance, node.js, delegates, ecmascript-8

What I want to do is for an example command have it defined in its own file - e.g. **command.js** - and the same for the other methods. I want to make a separate file for every module - for example "command.js", "vanish.js" and I can not think of a way to call the methods without making a big switch statement in a file where I would require all the "modules".

This is how I do it currently:

```
const client = require('../../../src/bot');
const logger = require('../../../config/logger');
const {isCommand} = require('../../../helpers/checkCommand');
const {addCommand, deleteCommand, updateCommand} = require('../../../db/commandFunctions')
const isAuthorized = require('../isAuthorized');
const builtInCmdHelpers = require('../builtInCommandHelpers');

const USER_MODULES = 'everyone';
const MOD_MODULES = 'moderator';

const executeBuiltInCommand = async ({channel, args}, userstate) => {
  const isSubArg = await isCommandSubArg(args[1]);
  if(isSubArg) await builtInCmdHelpers[args[1]].apply(null, [{channel, args}, userstate]);
};

const command = async ({channel, args}, userstate) => {
  const canExecute = await isAuthorized(channel, userstate.badges, MOD_MODULES);
  if(canExecute) await executeBuiltInCommand({channel, args}, userstate);
};

const vanish = async ({channel}, {username}) => {
  const canExecute = await isAuthorized(channel, username, USER_MODULES);
  if(canExecute) {
    client.timeout(channel, username, 1, "VANISH")
      .catch((err) => {
      logger.error(err);
    });
  }
};



module.exports = {
  command,
  vanish,
};
```

This is how i execute the commands currently:

```
const executeBuiltIn = async ({channel, args}, userstate) => {
  await builtin[args[0]].apply(null, [{channel, args}, userstate]);
};
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to put each function in a separate file? E.g. one for `add`, one for `remove` , one for `edit`, etc.?

Comment: i mean a custom file for "command" and "vanish" i thought of using a index file where i would import the files command.js and vanish.js but when i did that it did not work. I moved add, remove, edit and show already to an own file.

Answer (score 2):

### Separate modules

You didn’t specify a file name for the code in the first block- is it something like *builtin.js*?

The code in the first block should be divisible into two files- one for `command` with `executeBuiltInCommand` and `MOD_MODULES`, and the other for `vanish` with `USER_MODULES`. They could be combined to a single module to replace the current file in the first block - what I presume is *builtin.js*.

### Simplify `.apply()` syntax

The ES6 feature [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) can be used to replace calls to `.apply()`.

For example:

> ```javascript
> if(isSubArg) await builtInCmdHelpers[args[1]].apply(null, [{channel,
> args}, userstate]);
> ```

can be simplified to:

```
if(isSubArg) await builtInCmdHelpers[args[1]](...[{channel, args}, userstate]);
```

However, since there is a fixed length on that array of arguments, the method can be called directly:

```
if(isSubArg) await builtInCmdHelpers[args[1]]({channel, args}, userstate);
```

Comment: I'm not sure .apply()/spread needed to be used in the first place. Couldn't it just be `builtInCmdHelpers[args[1]]({channel, args}, userstate)`?

Comment: Yes- that seems to be sufficient given that the array of args is not very variadic. Thanks for pointing that out!